# NSKeyedUnarchiver - Bad access

Tags: iphone, nskeyedarchiver

I was trying to archive an object into a plist file and load it later to fill a tableView.
It seems that the file gets archived correctly but I get a bad access when trying to get the value out of the file.

Am I doing something wrong?

This is where I save it

```
// Create some phonebook entries and store in array
NSMutableArray *book = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Phonebook *chris = [[Phonebook alloc] init];
chris.name = @"Christian Sandrini";
chris.phone = @"1234567";
chris.mail = @"christian.sandrini@example.com";
[book addObject:chris];
[chris release];

Phonebook *sacha = [[Phonebook alloc] init];
sacha.name = @"Sacha Dubois";
sacha.phone = @"079 777 777";
sacha.mail = @"info@yzx.com";
[book addObject:sacha];
[sacha  release];

Phonebook *steve = [[Phonebook alloc] init];
steve.name = @"Steve Solinger";
steve.phone = @"079 123 456";
steve.mail = @"steve.solinger@wuhu.com";
[book addObject:steve];
[steve release];

[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:book toFile:@"phonebook.plist"];
```

And here I try to get it out of the file and save it back into an array

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Load Phone Book
    NSArray *arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"phonebook.plist"];

    self.list = arr;

    [arr release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The part where I try to build a cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *PhoneBookCellIdentifier = @"PhoneBookCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PhoneBookCellIdentifier];

    if ( cell == nil )
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:PhoneBookCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    Phonebook *book = [self.list objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = book.name;   
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    return cell;
}
```

Here the bad access error

> Current language:  auto; currently
>   objective-c Assertion failed: (cls),
>   function getName, file
>   /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.5/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm,
>   line 3990. Assertion failed: (cls),
>   function getName, file
>   /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.5/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm,
>   line 3990. Assertion failed: (cls),
>   function getName, file
>   /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.5/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm,
>   line 3990. Assertion failed: (cls),
>   function getName, file
>   /SourceCache/objc4_Sim/objc4-427.5/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm,
>   line 3990.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the only problem, but you shouldn't be releasing arr in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on that a fraction: `unarchiveObjectWithFile` will return an autoreleased pointer. You don't locally `retain` it so you shouldn't `release`. Because you do, the object is subsequently deallocated and by the time you come to use it by calling `book.name`, it's not there.

(I'm assuming the `self.list` property is retaining appropriately so that the object will be kept around as long as you don't release here. If not, you'll need to fix that too.)

Comment: You are the man ;-) Removing the [arr release] solved the problem. Thanks a lot!